# GreenPlum generate_series function to migrate into HiveSQL

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We are migrating greenplum sql into hiveSQL migration and below statement needs to convert. kindly help us.

GREENPLUM SQL - generate_series:

```
SELECT d ::date AS start_date ,(d + interval '6 day')::date AS end_date ,('W'||row_number()over(order by d ::date)) Week
FROM generate_series(wdate
, idate
,interval '7 day') d
order by 1;
```

kindly help us.

Comment: What specific help do you need? Please be more specific in your ask.

Comment: OP needs a hive SQL which will generate date series like this `4-jan2021 10-Jan-2021 week 1 11-jan2021 17-Jan-2021 week 2 and so on`. Input would be 4-jan-2021. OP please add input and expected output too.

Comment: generate_series which is not available  similar in hive. how do we perform this. please help me

Comment: please add input and expected output

Comment: please validate below and advise

Comment: select date_add ('${hivevar:s3date}',s.i) as mon_first, date_add ('${hivevar:s3date}',s.i) as mon_last
from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff('${hivevar:s3date}','${hiveconf:DATA_DATE}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s